# multi language font issue on C# textboxes

Tags: c#, fonts, multilingual

In my C# winform, the user can insert both English and Farsi characters together.

My Problem is that the Farsi characters are shown smaller than English characters. I use font Homa which is a Farsi font. How can I change the size of text according to the language of the text?

Interesting part is that in my laptop the English characters appear differently from other computers. I have tested on windows seven.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.aspx

Comment: Might have a lookaround in that namespace :)

Comment: I don't think globalization can solve my problem because the user can insert both En and Fa charterers in a same time. for example "سلام Hi"

Comment: true. might come out as "[][] Hi". I am convinced Globalization might help (CultureInfo). will play around and check quick

Answer (score 0):

```
if (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name == "fa-IR") 
{
    richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Homa", 30);
}

//fa          fa-IR       Persian
//fa-IR       fa-IR       Persian (Iran)
```

Comment: Tested under my machine's cultureInfo (en-US)
and this code worked. This is what I understood you wanted